# Different solutions of the harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

This is a list question.

How many different solution methods are there for the harmonic oscillator?

I know three. The first is the algebraic method of the raise and lower operators, and the second is the 19th century different equation method, and the third one is by path integral (first calculate the partition function and then extract the spectrum).

Is there any more interesting solution?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a solution but the WKB method yields the exact energy eigenvalues.

Comment: Does anyone know any methods for solving (infinite dimensional) quantum mechanics problems that can't be used to solve the harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Apparently Lev Landau knew of 7 different ways, stating that "I cannot know ahead of time which one will be useful".  Unfortunately I cannot remember where I read this.